# Problem with Google translating Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, fun, translations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make users aware that they're reading translated content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/how-to-make-users-aware-that-theyre-reading-translated-content)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609028/problemas-de-css-entre-ie8-xp-e-ie8-seven) has been deleted but is a followup [of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608839/problems-with-css-between-ie8-xp-and-ie8-win7-closed).

Patricia [came to the site using Google Translator](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=pt-BR&langpair=en|pt&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611948/differences-in-ie8-behavior-between-xp-vista-win7&rurl=translate.google.com.br&twu=1&usg=ALkJrhiRqDfRbpsVsii5XdWEtRw7yVdIJg) and, as the top-frame is removed, was unaware that, actually, the community is English-speaking.

Comment: Ahahahahahaha! What a hilarious misunderstanding. But Google Translate does that to you, I have seen people assume the exact same thing.

Comment: well this is not really a feature request is it...

Comment: unless its: "feature request: fix the Internets"

Comment: @waffles I suppose it's a feature request to not break iframes for sites like Google Translate

Comment: @Yij, then it needs to be re-written

Comment: @waffles "fix the internets!" hahaha ;)

Comment: Weird the way it translates vote counts to spelled-out words

Comment: @Yi, I guess we could do that, but then again is it worth the effort of maintaining a whitelist, javascript hacks and so on for something that happens once or twice a year?

Comment: @wafles♦: shouldn't you have written @Yij, you know, first three letters?

Comment: closely related / almost-dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/how-to-make-users-aware-that-theyre-reading-translated-content

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: Actually, that one is the dupe (same user, different SO question). Didn't think of searching for "Patricia" before I posted that :)

Comment: @Piskvor: But yours is more informative, dupes do not necessarily qualify as such by being second

Answer (score 1):

["a sexta-feira, sempre na Islândia"](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=en&tl=pt&u=https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/always-friday-in-iceland/info&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&twu=1&usg=ALkJrhhjEAnHKgVncYP1bP-9wWpJoFW-YQ)

Comment: I really should do this sometimes... some of the translations are hilarious for the Chinese one. For instance, you're called 松饼, which is correct, and [always-friday-in-iceland] turns into 一直到星期五在冰, which is... less correct