# Localize SO and SE?

Tags: feature-request, languages, translations

I saw this [post](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22868/stackoverflow-com-in-vietnamese) on Area 51, spurring me to request that SO and perhaps the rest of the SE sites be "localized". However, this would lead to an additional requirement: Anyone using SO would need to have a language associated with their account. They would also have the option to view results in only their language.

Being an iOS developer, I would suggest that the developers of SO follow the model used by Apple in iOS to localize strings, thus making it easier for users to contribute to localizations. (Use placeholder strings in the main site and load a strings file for each language.)

Also, allow people to translate questions and mark them as such. Answers should also have translations.

Comment: I'm on iPad. Anyone who can, please correctly attach the link.

Comment: I only see one link in the beginning of your post, @Moshe.  what link, in particular are you talking about?

Comment: @studiohack: GraceNote already edited that in

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59298/the-stackoverflow-translation-project and related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow and the amusing-but-in-a-sad-way http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/how-to-make-users-aware-that-theyre-reading-translated-content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this, is that translation services are *pretty good* but not **perfect**.  Thus, there would be some misunderstandings, and a lot of stuff might not get translated at all...especially since many of the Stack Exchange sites deal with very **technical jargon** and such...

Instead, we should have clones, like the Area51 proposal that you linked, or something like that...