# Stack Overflow "standard" language

Tags: discussion, languages

don't you think that Stack Overflow's FAQ should mention that posts should be written in English?

I understand that, since the site itself is English-oriented, it should be clear. Also, there haven't been any problem until now. Nonetheless, clear rules are better than implicit rules, to me :-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59298/the-stack-exchange-translation-project , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/how-to-make-users-aware-that-theyre-reading-translated-content and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Comment: The meta FAQ does mention it now, at [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 7):

Probably no need. Non-English questions are extremely rare.

> clear rules are better than implicit rules

I would say, less rules is clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, wir gebrauchen schon ganz freiwillig die englische Sprache. 
[Oh well, we already use the English language completely voluntarily.]

Fact is that German Q&A sites similar to Stack Overflow simply lack the necessary number of users to get your problems solved in a short time. If I want answers, I have to post them here on one of the sites.

If I would post my questions in German, the expected result would be similarly frustrating. I haven't tried.

I've noticed that a number of helpers will silently fix my worst typos (thanks to you) and I can concentrate on the problem to solve.

And all that works without written rules.

Comment: Ни слова не понял.

Comment: Yeah if we pointed out we were cleaning up basic grammar issues it would be annoying ;) ... what I hate is when the post is so poorly written in English that I'm afraid I'm going to lose something of value on "cleanup"