# Automatic translator feature by connecting Google Translate?

Tags: feature-request, localization

How about putting a button (activated by a configuration option) to automatically connect with Google Translate, and translate any message into the user´s specified language without exiting from the page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're requesting. What do you mean by "by config"? What message are you suggesting we translate?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59298/the-stack-exchange-translation-project See also this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62939/how-to-make-users-aware-that-theyre-reading-translated-content

Answer (score 11):

Use Chrome?  I mean if you're wanting to utilize the Google Translate functionality, why tax SO (and family) with the processing burden.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OldTroll is right.

You could just bookmark the translator yourself and not let SE do all the work for you. Anyways, Google Translate doesn't always translate the text to the correct English version. It could be a big bummer when that does happen.

We do have sites in different languages in Area 51 currently in Commitment and ready to go to Beta testing and some graduated sites. Really, this is an English only site so no one can use other text unless you are replying to another person in their native language through commenting (please add translation) or you are in chat, which might confuse some English speakers there...

So really, the Google Translate program does not need to be implemented and there are now sites in different languages such as Stack Overflow in Portuguese.